# .htaccess rewrites folder name in wamp server when URL with parameters are passed

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ /PM/$1.php [NC,L]
```

My project is located in c:/wamp/www/PM/

HTML example:

a href="messages.php"

The above URL works fine by producing the url as localhost/PM/messages/  (note the / at the end)

But when I use the url as

a href="messages?id=1"

The above link produces the URL as localhost/messages/?id=1   (I'm wondering how /PM disappear when passing a parameter in the URL) and the page says 'The requested URL /messages/ was not found on this server.'

Comment: Do you have any .htaccess in `/PM` directory also? Also are there other rules as well?

Comment: this .htaccess is itself in the PM folder

Comment: There was another question. are there other rules as well?

Comment: No. Only those three lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in your `/PM/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /PM/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```